# Why is there a pronunciation difference between “break” and “break”fast?

Tags: pronunciation

I found that *break* sounds like *brake* and *break*fast uses **e** in *bed* vowel. I couldn’t find out why they sounds different.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually curious on this as well, so I did a little research and here's what I found.

> In brief, it's because breakfast preserves an older pronunciation of the word break.

Now for the long explanation.

In Middle English, at the time when the word breakfast was coined (some time in the mid 15th century), the pronunciation of "ea"  in the word break was a long /ɛː/ sound, and it was pronounced like breck (/bɹɛ:k/). The origin of the word break is from Old English brecan (to break). Previously in Old English there had been two words for breakfast: undernmete, and morgenmete.  The newer Middle English word replaced them.

Because the word fast was added to the word break, to make a new word, and the syllable break is stressed, while the second syllable fast is in the unstressed position, it sounds more like fest (/fəst/) - with the vowel being reduced to a schwa. This is simply a result of way that the stress patterns of the English language affect vowel sounds in unstressed positions. The 15th century pronunciation was /ˈbɹɛkfəst/, same then as now. The pronunciation has stuck.

Meanwhile, later during the Middle English and early Modern English periods the word break (the one without the word fast stuck on the end) was one of a set of words which were undergoing a vowel change as part of the Great Vowel Shift which affected the English language from around 1350 CE to 1600 CE. This vowel change however did not affect the word breakfast, but it did affect the word break, which eventually came to be pronounced with an /e:/ sound by around 1600 CE, and then eventually the /ei/ diphthong we are familiar with today in Modern English.

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-breakfast-pronounced-as-breck-fest)